# Making a Ball Bounce on the Screen

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm in the process of trying to make a **very** simple ball and paddle game in Python and have the ball moving on the screen with a paddle that moves from left to right.  But, the ball moves and hits the bottom of the screen and doesn't change direction, it just stops and slides against the wall.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk
import random

canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 400

root = Tk()
root.title("Ball and Paddle")
c = Canvas(root,width=canvas_width,height=canvas_height,background='orange')
c.pack()

paddle_color = 'blue'
paddle_width = 60
paddle_height = 10
paddle_start_x = canvas_width/2 - paddle_width/2
paddle_start_y = canvas_height - paddle_height - 20
paddle_start_x2 = canvas_width/2 + paddle_width/2
paddle_start_y2 = canvas_height - 20

paddle = c.create_rectangle(paddle_start_x,paddle_start_y,\
                        paddle_start_x2,paddle_start_y2,\
                        fill='blue', width=0)

ball_color = 'green'
ball_width = 20
ball_height = 20
ball_start_x1 = canvas_width/2 - ball_width/2
ball_start_y1 = canvas_height/2 - ball_height/2
ball_start_x2 = canvas_width/2 + ball_width/2
ball_start_y2 = canvas_height/2 + ball_height/2
ball_speed = 5

ball = c.create_oval(ball_start_x1, ball_start_y1, \
                 ball_start_x2, ball_start_y2, \
                 fill = ball_color, width = 0)
dx = 1
dy = 1

def ball_move():
    global dx, dy
    (bx1,by1,bx2,by2) = c.coords(ball)
    c.move(ball, dx, dy)
    if bx1 <= 0:
    dx = -dx
    if bx2 >= canvas_width:
        dx = -dx
    if by1 <= 0:
        dy = -dy
    if by2 >= canvas_height:
        dy = -dy
    root.after(ball_speed, ball_move)

def move_left(event):
    (x1,y1,x2,y2) = c.coords(paddle)
    if x1>0:
        c.move(paddle,-20,0)

def move_right(event):
    (x1,y1,x2,y2) = c.coords(paddle)
    if x2 < canvas_width:
        c.move(paddle, 20, 0)

c.bind('<Left>',move_left)
c.bind('<Right>',move_right)
c.focus_set()

root.after(ball_speed, ball_move)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Make sure to double check your indentation, especially after `if bx1 <= 0:`

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming that the `if bx1 <= 0:` indentation problem isn't actually present in your real code, and was just a transcription error when writing this post)

This occurs because the ball is getting "lodged" into the border of the screen, when by2 has a value of 401. You reverse dy, which makes it move up to 400 at the next frame. But then you reverse dy *again*, so it moves back down to 401.

This happens because you're creating the b* variables, then moving the ball, then doing boundary checking on the b* variables. You're effectively inspecting the position of the ball from the previous frame.

Try moving the `move` call to after the boundary check.

```
def ball_move():
    global dx, dy
    (bx1,by1,bx2,by2) = c.coords(ball)
    if bx1 <= 0:
        dx = -dx
    if bx2 >= canvas_width:
        dx = -dx
    if by1 <= 0:
        dy = -dy
    if by2 >= canvas_height:
        dy = -dy
    c.move(ball, dx, dy)
    root.after(ball_speed, ball_move)
```

Now your ball should bounce.

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you SO much for the assist!  The indentation wasn't the problem, but the move command was.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonPalmira If this answer was useful to you please upvote and / or select as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation issue:

```
def ball_move():
    global dx, dy
    (bx1,by1,bx2,by2) = c.coords(ball)
    c.move(ball, dx, dy)
    if bx1 <= 0:
    dx = -dx
    if bx2 >= canvas_width:
    ..snippet..
```

should be:

```
def ball_move():
    global dx, dy
    (bx1,by1,bx2,by2) = c.coords(ball)
    c.move(ball, dx, dy)
    if bx1 <= 0:
        dx = -dx              # indent corrected here!
    if bx2 >= canvas_width:
    ..snippet..
```

Comment: I agree that the code in the question has an indentation issue, but it can't be the cause of the OP's described problem. The ball wouldn't get stuck at the bottom of the screen because of an indentation error; the window wouldn't even appear if there was an indentation error.

Comment: on the machine I do current reviewing Tkinter isn't installed. So I can't check the script on functionality. OP could implement a threshold warning for debugging purpose. Something like: print value bx1, bx2 and see what happens. Something with swapping values back and forth.

Comment: aha.. I see Kevin got that too. but the ball should hit platform and bounch back. Aside of the platform it should vanish.